# char-array (string) with arbitrary number of elements in c

Tags: c

I have problem with assigning value to string array in c. The code is part of a hangman game

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int random = rand() % 5;

    char *sWords[] = {"banana", "apple", "GOAT", "jordan", "zhiki"};
    printf("%s\n", sWords[random]);

    char *sTempWord = sWords[random];

    char *sTempArr;
    for (int i = 0; sTempWord[i] != '\0'; i++)
        sTempArr[i] = '_';

    for (int i = 0; strlen(sTempArr); i++)
        printf("%c ", sTempArr[i]);
}
```

There are no errors, and when I run the program it just exits. The plan is to get random word from the list, create temporary array with the length of the randomly-selected word and assing all elements with value '_'.

Also, when I try to make array with constant value, (like `char sTempArr[len]` where `len=strlen(sTempWord)`, it says: **expression must have a constant value**

Comment: You never make the pointer variable `sTempArr` point anywhere, which means you can not use it in any usable way. Remake it as an array of a size big enough to hold the longest word *plus* the null-terminator (which you also need to add yourself).

Comment: Instead of `char sTempArr[len]`, you could allocate memory dynamically using `char *sTempArr=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*len+1);` which allocates space for `len` characters and one more for the null terminator. For that you'll also need to include `stdlib.h`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When declaring an array, the compiler needs to know the length at compile time (e.g. the value can't be a variable).

You can either create an initial empty array with a known number of items (you will need to make sure it's big enough to fit any word from `sWords`, including null terminator):

```c
char sTempArr[100];
```

or you can allocate dynamic memory at runtime with something like [`malloc()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc):

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

int len = strlen(sTempWord) + 1;   // +1 for '\0'
char *sTempArr; = malloc(len);

// ...

free(sTempArr);    // When you are done using the array
```

They are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not initialized pointer.

```
    char *sTempArr;
```

2. You do not null character terminate the string

```
    for (int i = 0; sTempWord[i] != '\0'; i++)
        sTempArr[i] = '_';
```

3. As the string is null character terminated you can't call `strlen`

```
    for (int i = 0; strlen(sTempArr); i++)
        printf("%c ", sTempArr[i]);
```

```
    char sTempArr[strlen(sTempWord) + 1];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; sTempWord[i] != '\0'; i++)
        sTempArr[i] = '_';
    sTempArr[i] = 0;

    for (i = 0; strlen(sTempArr); i++)
        printf("%c ", sTempArr[i]);
```